# I try to move an png image in Swift-SpriteKit, it crashed with an error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

code:

```
 var tree = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tree3")//tree3.png is the image 
            tree.position = CGPointMake(400, movingGround.size.height/2 +    tree.size.height/2)
            tree.zPosition = -0.5
            self.addChild(tree)

     func treeMove(){
            var moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-5, y: 0, duration: 1.0)
            tree3.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))

        }
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
   treeMove()
}
```

error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

(lldb) 
how to improve my code 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `runAction` on `tree3`, but your `SKSpriteNode` is named `tree`.

Answer (score 0):

tree3 is not initialized by the moment when you call runAction. Do you have it initialized somewhere else? What is expected logic that you are trying to implement? Does tree3 and tree should be the same object or different objects?